# What are the academic journals on Hinduism?

Tags: resource

Can anybody suggest any academic journal on Hindu studies where scholars publish their peer-reviewed article on Hindu Theology and Philosophy? I am talking about academic journals and not magazines.

Comment: This question can complement my question on META too: [Research Paper as Sources](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2208/research-paper-as-sources)

Comment: @Vivikta Thank you so much for the link.

Comment: Maybe a religious journal (?) It must contain peer-reviewed articles on Hinduism. Or an theological or philosophical journals (?). I dont think if there is some journal completely dedicated to Hinduism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the list of International peer-reviewed journals on Hinduism -

1. International Journal of Hindu Studies (https://www.springer.com/journal/11407/). This one is published by Springer. Springer publishes many academic journals.
2. Journal of Hindu Studies (https://academic.oup.com/jhs). This one is published by Oxford Academic (Oxford Centre for Hindu Studies)
3. Electronic Journal of Vedic Studies (https://crossasia-journals.ub.uni-heidelberg.de/index.php/ejvs/index). This journal is dedicated to only Vedic Studies as the name suggests.

Apart from these three dedicated journals on Hinduism, there are two more journals on Indic Religion & Philosophy, which obviously publish works on Hinduism and Hindu Philosophy. Both are published by Springer.

1. Journal of Indian Philosophy (https://www.springer.com/journal/10781)
2. Journal of Dharma Studies (https://www.springer.com/journal/42240)

Some people might find this [site](https://booksc.org) useful.

Comment: Oh, nice find..